# NuGet and handling updates for Framework and Core

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, nuget

A while back, I experimented with NuGets while I was working on some programs. Recently (especially when I learned how to make a Direct Linking Library, so two of my programs use any code that is identical), I noticed that there are NuGets made by Microsoft that have names, similar to those shown at the start of every cs file (example: System.IO). I recall that Microsoft was going to issue updates for .NET Framework through these, but I never found how to apply them. So, I'd like to ask the following questions:

1. Does Microsoft distributes .NET updates for programs written for Framework 4.6.x? If yes, how do I apply them to my program?
2. Do I need to distribute the DLL files as well when I release an update to a program?
3. In addition, what do NETCore and NETStandard Nugets do exactly? I tried to install a set of NETCore to a 4.6.2 program, but it couldn't install them due to a dependency error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: On windows, most of the main-.NET-libraries are already in the global assembly cache, I guess they are to be found in NuGet, as it is not mandatory for a computer to have them. Looking at dotnetcore and Linux, you will want to have a way to access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. .NET Framework itself is considered part of Windows, and Microsoft does provide periodical updates via its channels automatically. Usually you should do nothing, but if your apps depend on specific hot fixes, then you have to ship them in your installers.
2. Anything you added as NuGet packages becomes part of your apps, and you become responsible to keep them up-to-date. So with your own app updates, you should ship new assemblies from updated NuGet packages.
3. .NET Core apps bundle the runtime, so you are fully responsible to republish your apps with updated runtime frequently. Check Microsoft LTS/Current support policies at http://dot.net